# How to add an onClick event to an HTML radio button in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

I have multiple tabs on my page and currently I am binding all dropdownlists on every tab at page load.

I want to bind the dropdownlists only when the tab is selected. I also want to clear the gridviews when the tab is changed.

This is my HTML code

```html
<li>
   <input type="radio" id="tab1d"  name="tabs1" runat="server"/>
   <label for="tab1d">Search</label>
   <div id="tab-content1d" class="tab-content animated fadeIn" style="background-color:white; padding:10px; ">
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
           <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Select Platform"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="inputs" Width="150px"></asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Select Family Name"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="inputs" Width="150px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Select price Level"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="inputs" Width="150px" ></asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="buttons" OnClick="Button7_Click"/><br /><br />
               <div id="gdvLeft">
                   <asp:GridView ID="gdvFamilyname" runat="server" EnableViewState="True" class="grid" RowStyle-CssClass="rows"></asp:GridView>
               </div>
               <div id="gdvRight">
                   <asp:GridView ID="gdvQuantity" runat="server" EnableViewState="True"  class="grid" RowStyle-CssClass="rows"></asp:GridView>
               </div>
           </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </div>
   </li>
```

Comment: what have you tried ? Also can you indent your HTML well

Comment: Fixed code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Himani, Try like this -**

```
<input type="radio" value="Click Me" onclick="rdioClick();" />
```

In Javascript -

```
function rdioClick() {
            var GridView1 = document.getElementById('GridView1');
            GridView1.innerHTML = "";
        }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I tried that , it still didn't work. I also tried setting the data source of the gridview to null in the onclick event.

Comment: Please write your code what are you writing in javascript.